# How to get content using filter and match?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to search in the array if theres the string that Im looking for, to do that im using match

`const search_notes = array_notes.filter(notes => notes.real_content.toUpperCase().match(note.toUpperCase()));`

as you can see, search_notes will give me an array with all the strings that at least has a character from the input or match completely, but theres a problem, because when I write , ), [], + or any regex symbol in the input it will gives me this error:

[image]

how can i solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at documentation for the `match` method (for instance, [MDN's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)), you'll see that it accepts a `RegExp` object or a string, and if you give it a string, it passes that string into `new RegExp`. So naturally, characters that have special meaning in a regular expression need special treatment.

You don't need `match`, just [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes), which doesn't do that:

```
const search_notes = array_notes.filter(
    notes => notes.real_content.toUpperCase().includes(note.toUpperCase())
);
```

Comment: thanks <3, wait 9min and i will accept your answer ahah